# How stable is fiber?

Tags: food-science

Does cooking or grinding fiber or foods containing fiber (either soluble fiber or insoluble fiber) convert the fiber to sugar? Does changing the pH for example with the addition of vinegar or baking soda convert the fiber to sugar, with or without further processing? Thank you.

Comment: Where you thinking of starch/ carbohydrates instead of fibres? They can be partially converted into sugar by some cooking processes.

Comment: @quarague No. I meant fiber. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Dietary fiber [cannot be converted into sugar](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/nutritionsource/carbohydrates/fiber/#:%7E:text=Though%20most%20carbohydrates%20are%20broken,and%20blood%20sugar%20in%20check.) with any typical home food preparation processes. There are specific enzymes, used in some industrial processes, that can facilitate this conversion, but it is not possible with the ingredients you mention.  Fiber is also not digestible and passes through our bodies.

Comment: I am thinking, for example, of inulin, a soluble fiber made of a polymer of fructose. Agave syrup, which is essentially a high fructose syrup, is made commercially by heat hydrolysis of agave (mostly fructans like inulin). I don’t know how hot this heat hydrolysis is, but when we cook and eat foods rich in inulin, like garlic, artichokes, or added inulin in a baked good, does that inulin convert to fructose either by cooking or in the body’s digestive tract?